# Is it possible for MapViewOfFile to return the same address twice?

Tags: c++, windows

Good morning, Is it possible for MapViewOfFile to return the same address twice? However, UnmapViewOfFile misbehaves when it has to unmap the same address twice. We get an Error 487 : Invalid address. Here is some pseudo code which shows how we are using MapViewOfFile and UnMapViewOfFile:

```
retval =    UnmapViewOfFile(TmpPrevMapPtr);            
if (retval == 0){
    DWORD lasterr = GetLastError();
    printf("UNMAP Last Error = %d ...
      }

  MapPtr = (char*)::MapViewOfFile( hMapping, FILE_MAP_WRITE | FILE_MAP_READ,0,baseoff,
mappedlength);
  if (MapPtr == 0){
    throw cException(ERR_MEMORYMAPPING,TempFileName);
  }

  Thank you.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you did `UnmapViewOfFile` that virtual address is free to be used for other operation. So yes, the subsequent `MapViewOfFile` may return this address.

Comment: Naveen,  However, UnmapViewOfFile misbehaves when it has to unmap the same address twice. We get an Error 487 : Invalid address. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Frank: You did `MapViewOfFile` before doing `UnmapViewOfFile` second time? Else you will be unmapping an already freed address which is not allowed.

Comment: Naveen, Thank you for your reply. Naveen, Here is the sequence of events MapViewOfFile UnMapViewOfFile, MapViewOfFile UnMapViewOfFile, ...... In this scenario, is it possible for MapView Of File to return the same address twice. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: Yes, second `MapViewOfFile` can return the same address. However, in that case `UnmapViewOfFile` should also succeed.

Comment: Naveen, Thank for your reply. I thought MapViewOfFile can only reply unique addresses. Why does MapViewOfReturn the same address twice occasionally?

Comment: @Frank: As I said in my answer, once you do `UnmapViewOfFile` the freed virtual address is like any other free virtual address. So the OS may chose to use this particular address again when you do `MapViewOfFile`.

Comment: Naveen, Suppose we have the following sequence of events UnmapViewOfFile(0x20000000), 0x2000000 = MapViewOfFile(), UnmapViewOfFile(0x20000000). What would would be the last return value of UnMapViewFile(0x2000000)? Also , how about Linux and Unix with munmap(0x200000000, 65536) , 0x20000000 = mmap(), munmap(0x200000000, 65536)? Is it possible to predict what would happen with LInux? Thank you.